# Separate headers from sequences in fasta file without using Biopython

Tags: python, file, parsing, fasta

I have been trying to separate multiple DNA sequences from their header in a single fasta file by constructing a dictionary with Python 3.5 without using Biopython. I can not get it work right. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you very much. 
The header follows the sign '>'

Here is an example of a single fasta file:

```
>XM_021728176.1 PREDICTED: Ictidomys tridecemlineatus forkhead box N1 (Foxn1), transcript variant X1, mRNA
ATGGTGTCGCTACTCCCGCCACAGTCTGACGTCACGCTGCCTGGCCCCACCAGACTGGAGGGCGAGCCCC
AAGGGGACCTCATGCAGGCTCCGGGCCTCCCAGGCTCCCCTGCTCCACAGAGTAAGCACGCCGGCTTCAA
CTGCTCGTCATTTGTGCCCGACGGTCCTCCAGAGAGGGCACCCTCACTGCCCCCACACAGCCCGAGCATT
GCGTCACCAGGCCCCGAGCAAGTCCAGGGCCACTGCCCAGCCGGCCCTGGCCCAGGGCCTTTCCGGCTTT
CACCCTCAGATAAGTATCCTGGCTTTGGCTTTGAGGAGGGCCCAGCAAGCAGCCCTGGGCGCTACCTCAA
GGGCAACCACGTGCCCTTCCACCCATACAAGCGGCATTTCCATGAGGATATCTTCCCTGAAGCCCAGACC
GCCCTGGCCCTGGATGGACACTCCTTTAAGACCCCAGGGGCACTGGAGGCCTTTGAGGAGATCCCTGTGG
ACGTGGGGGAGGCCGAGGCCTTCCTGCCTGGTTTCCCTGCAGAGGCCTGGTGCAATGGGCTCCCTTACCC
CAGCCAGGAGCATGGCCAAGTCCTGCAGGCGTCAGAGGTCAAGATCAAGCCTCCAGCTCTGGAGAATGGT
CCTGGGATGTACTGCTACCAACCCCCCTTGCAGCACATGTACTGCCCTTCCCAGCCCCCTTTCCACCAGT
ATTCACAGGGTGGTGGCAGCTACCCTGTACCCTACCTGGGCTCCTCTCACTATCCATACCAGCGGATCGC
ACCCCAGGCCAGCGCTGATGGGCACCAGCCGCTCTTCCCCAAACCCATCTACTCCTACAGCATCCTCATC
TTCATGGCCCTCAAGAACAGCAAAACTGGAAGCCTGCCTGTCAGCGAGATCTACAATTTTATGACGGAGC

>XM_006532268.2 PREDICTED: Mus musculus forkhead box N1 (Foxn1), transcript variant X15, mRNA
CTCTCCAGGGAGACTCAGGATCAGGATGCTGCTGTGGAAGTGCAGAGAGCTCTGCTGACACAGCCTGGAA
TGGACAGCCTCGCCTGGCGCTGAGCCCCAAGGCCTCCCAGCTGCTCTGTGGTGCTGGGTCAGGGTTCTAC
AACAACAGTTCAGAAGGGGACTGGGTGATGGTGTCGCTACTCCCTCCGCAGTCTGACGTCACACTTCCAG
GCTCCACCCGACTGGAGGGCGAACCCCAAGGGGACCTCATGCAGGCTCCGGGCCTCCCAGACTCCCCTGC
CCCACAGAACCAGGGGTCAGAGGTCAAGGTCAAGCCCCAAGCTCTGGACAGTGGTCCTGGGATGTACTGC
TACCAGCCTCCCTTGCAACATATGTACTGTTCTTCTCAGCCTGCCTTCCATCAGTACTCCCCGGGTGGAG
GCAGCTACCCTGTGCCCTACCTGGGCTCACCTCACTATCCCTATCAGAGGATTGCACCCCAGGCCAACGC
CGAAGGTCACCAGCCACTCTTCCCAAAGCCCATCTACTCTTACAGCATCCTCATCTTCATGGCCCTTAAG
AACAGTAAGACCGGAAGCCTTCCAGTCAGTGAAATCTACAATTTCATGACGGAGCACTTCCCTTACTTCA
AGACTGCTCCTGATGGCTGGAAGAATTCTGTTCGCCATAACCTGTCCCTCAACAAGTGCTTTGAGAAGGT
GGAGAATAAATCCGGAAGTTCCTCTCGAAAGGGCTGTCTGTGGGCCCTCAATCCTTCCAAAATCGACAAG
ATGCAGGAAGAACTGCAGAAGTGGAAGAGGAAAGACCCCATTGCTGTGCGCAAAAGCATGGCCAAACCAG
AAGAGCTGGACAGCCTCATTGGAGACAAAAGGGAAAAACTGGGCTCTCCGCTGCTGGGCTGTCCACCCCC
TGGGCTGGCAGGCCCAGGTCCCATCCGGCCCATGGCACCATCAGCTGGTCTTTCCCAGCCTCTGCACCCA
```

Answer (score 2):

How about the following:

```
import sys

sequences = {}

with open(sys.argv[1]) as fasta:
    header = None
    data = ''

    for line in fasta:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            if header and data:
                sequences[header] = data
            data = ''
            header = line.rstrip()
        else:
            data += line.rstrip()

    if header and data:
        sequences[header] = data  # deal with the last one in the file

for header, data in sequences.items():
    print('{}; {}bp'.format(header, len(data)))
```

> How would you analyze each record in the dictionary. Lets say you
>   wanna count a number of letters in the sequence?

The code makes a dictionary with the headers as the keys and the concatenated data as the value.  I've added a loop to pull out the headers and data and print out the header with the data length.

Comment: Thank you so much.  It works well.  How would you analyze each record in the dictionary. Lets say you wanna count a number of letters in the sequence?

Comment: @Sergey_yaklichk, I've added a loop to the end of the code that prints out the headers with the sequence length appended.  Normally I'd use Biopython, instead of simply `len()`, for this but you requested that I not.